# AnkhSVN 2.4.11610.27 not available in visual studio 2012 sp2

Tags: ankhsvn

I've installed Visual Studio Prof. 2012 with SP 2 and AnkhSVN 2.4.11610.27. Both setup processes were successfull (no errors) but I can't see the AnkhSVN Plug-In in Visual Studios source control options and it is not listed in the about dialog.
Uninstall and repair from AnkhSVN's setup and starting Visual Studio with /resetsettings or /resetskippkgs did not help.
Has anybody an idea?
Thanks
Andreas

Comment: I'm getting this problem with VS 2010 Pro SP1 too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Add/Remove Programs and choose AnkhSVN (or re-run the MSI), choose Change, and there make sure 'Register in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012' is enabled.